# android google map marker placing

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

In my Android application I need to place marker at exact position on map. I pin a marker on map with 51.507351, -0.127758 (London) location. I used the following code to do the work.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758)).icon(
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.q_icon))));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758), 20));
```

And this my marker drawable image:

[image]

Now my problem is, the "Q" symbol is placed at the location of 51.507351, -0.127758. I need to place marker at the position where bottom arrow starts.

Please see the picture so that you can understand my question.

How can I do this? please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

The logic behind how the markers are anchored is something like this for a 4px-by-2px image:

```
        0,0      0.5,0.0        1,0
        *-----+-----+-----+-----*
        |     |     |     |     |
        |     |     |     |     |
  0,0.5 +-----+-----+-----+-----+ 1,0.5
        |     |     |   X |     |           (U, V) = (0.7, 0.6)
        |     |     |     |     |
        *-----+-----+-----+-----*
        0,1      0.5,1.0        1,1
```

Also take into consideration that based on your bitmap resource, it could be positioned a little different than you would expect, because they actually approximate to the nearest snap position. So in the example above, your anchor points will snap to this position:

```
 *-----+-----+-----+-----*
 |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----X-----+   (X, Y) = (3, 1)
 |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |
 *-----+-----+-----+-----*
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float))

Answer (score 17):

Use `MarkerOption`'s `anchor` method: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)

For your case:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
.anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
// Rest of the properties follow
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .title("Hello world")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758)).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeResource(getResources(),
                                R.drawable.q_icon))).anchor(0.5f, 1f));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    new LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758), 20));
```

Comment: Worked here. Spaciba o_O