# Google Maps Android polylines are not crossing the center of markers

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

From the image, the Polylines are touching the center bottom of the Markers. I need the Polylines to touch the center of the Marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `anchor` of your marker by calling

```
marker.setAnchor()
```

> The position at which to anchor an image in correspondence to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the image.

[official doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.anchorPoint)

Comment: Thanks, more about how the anchor works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437865/android-google-map-marker-placing/37480001#37480001